# Did the space shuttle have a stall warning system (such as a stick shaker)?

Tags: stall, space-shuttle

I've been wondering about this, but I can't find any sources one way or the other:

Was the space shuttle equipped with a stick shaker and\or other stall warning system?

Comment: Interesting question

Comment: I remember there was a movie where a shuttle stalled before any warning was given except one from a chase jet. But that's just a movie.

Comment: Hey, there was a little blinkie light that came on at 1:13 in https://youtu.be/rKHW39mShF4! Granted, it's not very specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shuttle was not built with this capability. NASA AMES had a project [MIDAS](https://human-factors.arc.nasa.gov/groups/midas/application/shuttlemidas.html) intended to improve the shuttle's cockpit information display and management. In its list of problems to address:

> Finally, there is no warning or guidance/autopilot limiting when approaching a stall on entry.